# How to get base url in struts2

Tags: struts2, struts

I am using struts2 framework & in struts1 we use to point it from base url

```
<html:rewrite page='/stylesheets/m.css'/>
```

Please tell me how to do the same in sturts2

Comment: not sure what you mean exactly by base URL? you can use simple `getRequestURI()`

Comment: Where do you need the url in the action or the view? You can use the struts2 url tag to produce a base url (no namespace or action) and it is very convenient way to produce portable urls to actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Quaternion commented

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<s:url value="/stylesheets/m.css"/>" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/stylesheets/m.css" type="text/css">
```

[Strut2 UrlTag](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/docs/using-struts-2-tags.html)